# arr.last returns nil in recursive add_numbers

Tags: arrays, ruby, recursion

I'm sorry but I couldn't think of good title

My question is, why does this recursive function to add the numbers in an array work:

```
def add_numbers(arr)
  return arr.first if arr.size == 1
  return nil if arr.empty?


  arr.pop + add_numbers(arr[0..-1])
end
```

but not this one:

```
def add_numbers(arr)
  return arr.first if arr.size == 1
  return nil if arr.empty?

  arr = arr[0...-1]
  arr.last + add_numbers(arr[0..-1])
end
```

The error I receive is

```
TypeError: nil can't be coerced into Fixnum
```

because arr.last is nil at the very last step, I suppose. I've tried doing a memory model on paper but I still can't figure out why the first isn't equivalent to the second.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it worked well but with a bad result the problem is using:

```
arr = arr[0...-1]
```

instead of

```
arr.pop
```

with pop you modify arr doing it smaller with out de last number and returns last number, and with the other you get the array smaller before getting the last:

```
    [32] pry(main)> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
    => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    [33] pry(main)> a.pop
    => 5
    [34] pry(main)> a
    => [1, 2, 3, 4]
    [35] pry(main)> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
    => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    [36] pry(main)> a = a[0...-1]
    => [1, 2, 3, 4]
    [37] pry(main)> a.last
    => 4
```

let's add some debugger to your functions:

```
    def add_numbers(arr)

      puts "array = #{arr}"
      puts "length = #{arr.length}"

      return arr.first if arr.size == 1
      return nil if arr.empty?


      arr.pop + add_numbers(arr[0..-1])
    end

    def add_numbers(arr)

      puts "array = #{arr}"
      puts "length = #{arr.length}"


      return arr.first if arr.size == 1
      return nil if arr.empty?

      arr = arr[0...-1]
      arr.last + add_numbers(arr[0..-1])
    end
```

with the following output respectively:

```
[1] pry(main)> 
[1] pry(main)* => :add_numbers
[2] pry(main)> add_numbers [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
length = 5
array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
length = 4
array = [1, 2, 3]
length = 3
array = [1, 2]
length = 2
array = [1]
length = 1
=> 15
[11] pry(main)> 
[11] pry(main)* => :add_numbers
[12] pry(main)> add_numbers [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
length = 5
array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
length = 4
array = [1, 2, 3]
length = 3
array = [1, 2]
length = 2
array = [1]
length = 1
=> 11
```

so you should change the last function to something like this:

```
def add_numbers(arr)

  puts "array = #{arr}"
  puts "length = #{arr.length}"


  return arr.first if arr.size == 1
  return nil if arr.empty?

  arr.last + add_numbers(arr[0...-1])
end
```

with the following output

```
[39] pry(main)> add_numbers [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
length = 5
array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
length = 4
array = [1, 2, 3]
length = 3
array = [1, 2]
length = 2
array = [1]
length = 1
=> 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose

```
arr = [1,2,3]
```

In the first case,

```
last = arr.pop
  #=> 3
arr
  #=> [1,2]
arr[0..-1]
  #=> [1,2]
last + add_numbers(arr[0..-1])
  #=> 3 + add_numbers([1,2])
```

In the second case,

```
arr[0..-1] 
  #=> [1,2,3]
arr = arr[0...-1]
  #=> [1,2]
arr[0..-1]
  #=> [1,2]
arr.last + add_numbers(arr[0..-1])
  #=> 2 + add_numbers([1,2])
```

Answer (score 0):

In a range, `..` is inclusive, `...` is exclusive. If `arr = [1, 2, 3]`, `arr[0..-1] == [1, 2, 3]` while `arr[0...-1] == [1, 2]`

On the first iteration of your second method, here's your last line

```
2 + add_numbers([1, 2])
```

Compare that with your working method

```
3 + add_numbers([1, 2])
```

You will definitely end up with the wrong results, but you shouldn't be getting a `nil` error if all of your inputs are integers. So the question is, what's your input?
`